# Difference between OfType<>() and checking type in Where() extension

Tags: c#, linq

Other than readability, what is the difference between the following linq queries and when and why would I use one over the other:

```
IEnumerable<T> items = listOfItems.Where(d => d is T).Cast<T>();
```

and

```
IEnumerable<T> items = listOfItems.OfType<T>();
```

**Update:**
Dang, sorry introduced some bugs when trying to simplify my problem

Comment: The difference is that the first one won't compile, will it?

Comment: Probably means: `listOfItems.Where(d => d is T).Cast<T>()`

Comment: Your updated code still won't compile. You can't just cast `IEnumerable<Somthing>` to `T` and assign it to `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let us compare three methods (pay attention to generic arguments):

1. `listOfItems.Where(t => t is T)` called on `IEnumerable<X>` will still return `IEnumerable<X>` just filtered to contain only elements of the type `T`.
2. `listOfItems.OfType<T>()` called on `IEnumerable<X>` will return `IEnumerable<T>` containing elements that can be casted to type `T`.
3. `listOfItems.Cast<T>()` called on `IEnumerable<X>` will return `IEnumerable<T>` containing elements casted to type `T` or throw an exception if any of the elements cannot be converted.

And `listOfItems.Where(d => d is T).Cast<T>()` is basically doing the same thing twice - `Where` filters all elements that are `T` but still leaving the type `IEnumerable<X>` and then `Cast` again tries to cast them to `T` but this time returning `IEumerable<T>`.

Comment: Sigh... tried to simplify question but ended up introducing a bug. Have updated to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @ajbeaven ok, removed part of the answer pointing this out for second line, but still - first line is incorrect.

Comment: @Krizz.  How is the first line incorrect?  Seems like a valid thing to want to cast for considering the elements in the list will be of type T

Comment: @dreza - first line is incorrect because it won't compile, run your visual studio and check :) - it is because you cannot cast `IEnumerable<X>` to `T`.

Comment: @Krizz - hmmm, I did run it in my visual studio and not only did it compile it didn't bomb out on that line...

Comment: @dreza - ah, I see now, the OP has updated his answer providing new version of first line, previously it was `IEnumerable<T> items = (T)listOfItems.Where(d => d is T)`

Answer (score 3):

`listOfItems.Where(d => d is T)` returns an `IEnumerable<U>` (where U is the type of the items in listOfItems), containing only items of type T.

`listOfItems.OfType<T>()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

If I take a few liberties with your example and crank it out in LINQPad, here's what I get:

**Methods**

```
List<T> GetNumbers<T>(List<T> nums){
    return nums.Where(d => d is T).ToList<T>();
}

List<T> GetNumbersOfType<T>(List<T> nums){
    return nums.OfType<T>().ToList<T>();
}
```

**IL**

```
GetNumbers:
IL_0000:  ldarg.1     
IL_0001:  ldnull      
IL_0002:  ldftn       05 00 00 2B 
IL_0008:  newobj      0A 00 00 0A 
IL_000D:  call        06 00 00 2B 
IL_0012:  call        07 00 00 2B 
IL_0017:  ret         

GetNumbersOfType:
IL_0000:  ldarg.1     
IL_0001:  call        08 00 00 2B 
IL_0006:  call        07 00 00 2B 
IL_000B:  ret
```

I'm not an IL expert, but it looks like the `GetNumbers` method (which uses the `Where` syntax) creates a new object each time through the loop, and so probably consumes a bit more memory than the `GetNumbersOfType` method (which uses `OfType`).

Comment: Not necessarily. The `call` statements call out to what are here unknown (and different) methods, which may have completely different impacts to running time and space which are indicated with this set of IL. Since both `Where` and `OfType` create a new iterator object, my guess is the `Where` was inlined.

Comment: The difference in the IL is that the first one creates a delegate. I think that should be expected, that's what the code says, after all.

Comment: @codekaizen, how is inlining relevant to this? There is certainly no inlining going on in the IL. In general, the C# compiler doesn't do inlining, the JIT compiler does.

Comment: Even though it's very interesting, I don't think this is the kind of answer the OP was looking for ;)

Comment: Right, ok perhaps it's not inlined; that was speculation anyway. My point about efficiency still stands. It's anyone's guess until you measure it.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, there is no difference to the <strike>compiled</strike> runtime profile of the compiled code. `OfType<T>` returns a `OfTypeIterator` which internally does an `is` test and `yield return`s those which match.

Comment: No difference in the compiled code... really? Perhaps you should think again about it ;). Even the return type is not the same...

Comment: In terms of runtime characteristics... they are essentially the same, even though the types are different. Further, I'm answering the questioner's intended code, not what he posted.

Comment: It is functionally almost the same thing, but it compiles to something quite different, so your first sentence is plain wrong...

Comment: I fixed the wording to express my intent. However, even though, the compiled code won't be that much different from each other, since the `OfType` does the same thing as the `Where` predicate in this case.

Comment: @codekaizen Thanks for your answer. This is closer to what I was trying to get across with my question (didn't help that I introduced bugs when simplifying).

Comment: @ajbeaven - glad to help; I guessed your intent since it was obvious the code you had wouldn't compile as is. I thought the question's intent was pretty clear.