# Exclude types form IEnumerable with linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

How can I filter out objects based on their derived type with linq-to-objects?

I am looking for the solution with the best performance.

The classes used:

```
abstract class Animal { }
class Dog : Animal { }
class Cat : Animal { }
class Duck : Animal { }
class MadDuck : Duck { }
```

I know of three methods: Use the `is` keyword, use the `Except` method, and to use the `OfType` method.

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>
{
    new Cat(),
    new Dog(),
    new Duck(),
    new MadDuck(),
};

// Get all animals except ducks (and or their derived types)
var a = animals.Where(animal => (animal is Duck == false));
var b = animals.Except((IEnumerable<Animal>)animals.OfType<Duck>());

// Other suggestions
var c = animals.Where(animal => animal.GetType() != typeof(Duck))

// Accepted solution
var d = animals.Where(animal => !(animal is Duck));
```

Comment: What if you have a `MadDuck`, which inherits from a `Duck`? Should that be returned or not? And, btw, what are you trying to achieve? Use of `is` and runtime type-checking might indicate design problems.

Comment: Good question. In this specific case I would like the subclasses of Duck to be excluded as well. That would make my option `b` invalid as they compare the type but not the inheritance.

Comment: Regarding my second questioin: from an OOP standpoint, other parts of your code shouldn't usually be concerned with actual types of your objects. The should know "as little as possible". That's why I wonder why you are doing this.

Comment: @Groo There indeed is an design problem in the code that provided the data. Therefore I need to remove specific derived classes to 'clean up' the provided data.

Comment: @MarcelJackwerth Good question. I am looking for the best performing solution. I've edited the question to include this.

Comment: @Aphelion: The real question is, since you have all the code except for the `Stopwatch`, why you asked this rather than just figured out the performance results by yourself.

Comment: @Will Point taken. Thank you. Now that I do have a list of options, the Stopwatch is indeed the next step to take. Actually I have updated the question with additional suggestions I got from the answers of my initial question. At that time I had only 2 suggested options.  I updated the question for future searches (by other SO users) so they can find the suggested and best option in one simple list.

Comment: @Aphelion: Gotcha.  Not sure if that's worth it.  Typically, someone with a similar question would search and find yours, then read the answers.  So there isn't that much need for editing the question with details from answers...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to also exclude subclasses of Duck, then the `is` is best.  You can shorten the code to just `.Where(animal => !(animal is Duck));`

Otherwise, sll's recommendation of GetType is best

Comment: As I want to exclude the subclasses and this is a shorter and more readable notation I have accepted your answer.

Comment: I don't believe this beats OfType<Duck>().

Answer (score 4):

- Solution using `Except()` is quite heavy.
- Keep in mind that solution `is` - would return true even some `SomeDuck` class inherited from `Duck`

  ```
  class SomeDuck : Duck
  ...
  // duck is Duck == true
  var duck = new SomeDuck();
  ```

An other solution could be:

```
animals.Where(animal => animal.GetType() != typeof(Duck))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have included your suggestion into the question.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Difference between OfType<>() and checking type in Where() extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012184/difference-between-oftype-and-checking-type-in-where-extension) the OfType call is equivalent to your option (a), albeit with *is Duck==true*, so based on that I would say stick to option (a).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want `Duck` nor any subclass of `Duck` to be returned, you need to use the `IsAssignableFrom` method:

```
animals.Where(animal => !animal.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Duck)));
```

Comment: Nice. I have never used `IsAssignableFrom` before. I wonder that the performance is for this method. Sounds like a good case for some profiling.

Comment: I'd expect it to be as fast as a `as` cast then null check.